# How to perform an ANCOVA in R

Tags: r, ancova

I want to perform an ANCOVA analysis of data concerning density of plant epiphytes. At first, I would like to know if there is any difference in plant density between two slopes, one N and one S, but I have other data such as altitude, canopy openness and height of the host plant. I know that my covariate would have to be the two slopes (N and S). I built this model that runs in R and although I have no idea if it performs well. Also I would like to know what the difference is if I use the symbol `+` or `*`.

```
model1 <- aov(density~slope+altitude+canopy+height)
summary(model1)
model1
```

Comment: + will calculate main effects only, * will estimate interactions between factors connected with *.  ANCOVA frameworks usually estimate only a main effect of the continuous factor, but interactions between all grouped factors.

Answer (score 16):

The basic tool for this is `lm`; note that `aov` is a wrapper for `lm`.

In particular, if you have some grouping variable (factor), $g$, and a continuous covariate $x$, the model `y ~ x + g` would fit a main effects ANCOVA model, while `y ~ x * g` would fit a model which includes interaction with the covariate. `aov` will take the same formulas.

Pay particular attention to the `Note` in the help on `aov`.

As for `+` vs `*`, russellpierce  pretty much covers it, but I'd recommend you look at `?lm` and `?formula` and most especially section 11.1 of the manual *[An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf)* that comes with R (or you can find it online if you haven't figured out how to find it on your computer; most easily, this involves finding the "Help" pull down menu in either R or RStudio).

Comment: suppose i have two group factors $g_1,g_2$, and two covariate $x_1,x_2$, with my model being
$$y_{ij}=\mu+\alpha_i+\eta_j+x_{ij1}\gamma_1+x_{ij2}\gamma_2+\epsilon_{ij}$$
Does y~g_1+g_2+x_1+x_2 does the same trick?
Do the F values obtained against x_1 and x_2 test $\gamma_1=0$ and $\gamma_2=0$ respectively?

Comment: Not sure how I missed this. Yes. .... and if you want to test both at once, fit both with and without them and pass the fitted lm objects to `anova` (you'll soon see if you give them in the wrong order because some SS will be negative if you do)

Answer (score 10):

I recommend getting and reading *Discovering Statistics using R* by Field. He has a nice section on ANCOVA.

To run ANCOVA in R load the following packages:

```
car
compute.es
effects
ggplot2
multcomp
pastecs
WRS
```

If you are using `lm` or `aov` (I use `aov`) make sure that you set the contrasts using the "contrasts" function before doing either `aov` or `lm`. R uses non-orthogonal contrasts by default which can mess everything up in an ANCOVA. If you want to set orthogonal contrasts use:

```
contrasts(dataname$factorvariable)=contr.poly(# of levels, i.e. 3)
```

then run your model as

```
model.1=aov(dv~covariate+factorvariable, data=dataname)
```

To view the model use:

```
Anova(model.1, type="III")
```

Make sure you use capital "A" `Anova` here and not `anova`. This will give results using type III SS.

`summary.lm(model.1)` will give another summary and includes the R-sq. output.

```
posth=glht(model.1, linfct=mcp(factorvariable="Tukey"))  ##gives the post-hoc Tukey analysis
summary(posth) ##shows the output in a nice format.
```

If you want to test for homogeneity of regression slopes you can also include an interaction term for the IV and covariate. That would be:

```
model=aov(dv~covariate+IV+covariate:IV, data=dataname)
```

If the interaction term is significant then you do not have homogeneity.

Comment: Why do non-orthogonal contrasts mess everything up?

Comment: To answer the question above about "why non-orthogonal contrasts mess everything up". The answer is that R defaults to non-orthogonal (i.e. difference between means) which can cause problems if you want to see the contribution of each IV separately. When we specify orthogonal contrasts we tell R that we want the SS for the IV's to be completely partitioned and non-overlapping. In this way we can see the variation attributed to each predictor cleanly and clearly. If you do not specify, R defaults to a more liberal approach to the contrast.

Comment: Why the interest in type III SS?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a complementary documentation http://goo.gl/yxUZ1R of the procedure suggested by @Butorovich. In addition, my observation is that when the covariate is binary, using summary(lm.object) would give same IV estimate as generate by Anova(lm.object, type="III").

Comment: It isn't clear that this is supposed to be an answer. Is it? If so, please edit to clarify. If it is a question, please ask by clicking the `ASK QUESTION` at the top & asking it there. Then we can help you properly.

Comment: Agreed. The message has been revised as an (complementary) answer to the previous one.