# Would I use a MANOVA or Multiple Regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, biostatistics, manova

I was wondering if you could help me in determining which test to use. I want to look at the differences in prosomal width of male and female horseshoe crabs based on age (1,1.5, 2, 2.5, 3). I had originally thought that I would use a MANOVA for this, but I do not think that is the case because I have two predictor variables (age and sex), and one response (Prosomal Width), whereas it says a MANOVA is used for two or more response variables. Would I use multiple regression instead?

Comment: Check out the discussion [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190984/anova-vs-multiple-linear-regression-why-is-anova-so-commonly-used-in-experiment), which runs down the key differences between ANOVA and regression. In essence, they are the same with some key differences in terms of statistical tests (f versus t). In your case, ANOVA or multiple regression both work.