# Regression or ANOVA

Tags: regression

on the basis of experimental design and qualitative/quantitative variables, how can i decide either i should go for Regression or ANOVA ( say a split plot design with 4 different irrigation level in main plot, 4 varieties in subplot, 3 replication)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANOVA vs multiple linear regression? Why is ANOVA so commonly used in experimental studies?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190984/anova-vs-multiple-linear-regression-why-is-anova-so-commonly-used-in-experiment)

Comment: Regression and ANOVA are the same model. But, here, it looks like you need a multilevel model, although more detaisl would help.

Answer (score 4):

ANOVA is just a specific kind of regression. So either way, you're doing a regression.

First, check if you satisfy the assumptions required for an ANOVA. If you don't then you will need to figure out what other type of regression to do. With your minimal information it's impossible to give you more detailed advice.