# What sort of test to use when the ANCOVA has a categorical DV?

Tags: ancova, dependent-variable

I am carrying out some research, and I realised that my DV is going to be categorical.
I originally planned on carrying out an ANCOVA; I have 1 IV with three levels, 1 DV and 4 covariates. After doing some revision, I realised that my DV will need to be categorial( yes, no)- but I am not sure what test to run- any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What would you do for a continuous dependent variable (DV)?

Comment: Is the dependent variable binary ?  That is, it can only have one of two categories - *Yes* or *No* ?  If so, you can use logistic regression.  The model will have a form similar to ancova, but will be a *generalized* linear model rather than a *general* linear model.

Comment: yes, it is binary.  How would a logistic regression work with the covariates?

Comment: You just do the logistic regression with the covariates in the model. Do you know how to interpret ANCOVA (and ANOVA for that matter) as linear regression?

Comment: It has been a while since I worked with regression, let alone interpreting ANCOVA (and ANOVA for that matter) as linear regression. So I will have to revise that. Any suggestions on readings( articles, books etc...)?

Comment: We must have a bunch of good stuff on here; I would welcome links from others. For a book, I learned this stuff from Agresti’s *Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models”, though not once did my graduate classes mention ANCOVA. I only know about it because it saw it written on a board when I was on campus a few weeks after graduation, remembered having heard that term before I studied statistics in detail, looked up ANCOVA on Wikipedia, and realized it’s just a special case of linear regression.

Comment: It will be important for you to understand ANCOVA as a regression in order for any responses to your question to make sense, as the answer is basically just to stick a link function on the left side with your dependent variable.

Comment: You might also mention which software package you intend to use.  This should be straightforward in any capable statistical analysis package.

Comment: See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/190984/28500) on this site, and its links, for how AN(C)OVA can be considered a form of linear regression, with categorical predictors for the ANOVA factors and continuous predictors for the covariates (C) to adjust for. Or use this site's search function to find many more, like [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/175246/28500) and [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/555/28500).

Comment: thank you, for your help